# Sample accurate extraction of chunks of audio using AVFoundation

Tags: audio, avfoundation, core-audio, avasset, avassetreader

## Problem

I am looking to extract sample-accurate ranges of LPCM audio from audio tracks within video files. Currently, I'm looking to achieve this using `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` against an `AVAssetTrack` delivered from reading a `AVURLAsset`.

Despite preparing and ensuring the asset is initialized using `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` set to `YES`, seeking to a sample-accurate position within an asset seems to be inaccurate.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @(YES) };
_asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:fileURL options:options];
```

This manifests itself with e.g. variable bit-rate encoded AAC streams. While I know that VBR audio streams present a performance overhead in seeking accurately, I'm willing to pay this provided I am delivered accurate samples.

When using e.g. Extended Audio File Services and the `ExtAudioFileRef` APIs, I can achieve sample-accurate seeks and extraction of audio. Likewise with `AVAudioFile`, as this builds on top of `ExtAudioFileRef`.

The issue, however, is I would also like to extract audio from media containers that the audio-file only APIs reject, but which *are* supported in AVFoundation via `AVURLAsset`.

## Method

A sample accurate time range for extraction is defined using `CMTime` and `CMTimeRange`, and set on the `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`. Samples are then iteratively extracted.

```
-(NSData *)readFromFrame:(SInt64)startFrame
      requestedFrameCount:(UInt32)frameCount
{
    NSUInteger expectedByteCount = frameCount * _bytesPerFrame;
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:expectedByteCount];
    
    //
    // Configure Output
    //

    NSDictionary *settings = @{ AVFormatIDKey               : @( kAudioFormatLinearPCM ),
                                AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved : @( NO ),
                                AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey   : @( NO ),
                                AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey       : @( YES ),
                                AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey      : @( 32 ),
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey       : @( 2 ) };

    AVAssetReaderOutput *output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:_track outputSettings:settings];

    CMTime startTime    = CMTimeMake( startFrame, _sampleRate );
    CMTime durationTime = CMTimeMake( frameCount, _sampleRate );
    CMTimeRange range   = CMTimeRangeMake( startTime, durationTime );

    //
    // Configure Reader
    //

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:_asset error:&error];

    if( !reader )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "avf : failed to initialize reader\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "avf : %s\n%s\n", error.localizedDescription.UTF8String, error.localizedFailureReason.UTF8String );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    [reader addOutput:output];
    [reader setTimeRange:range];
    BOOL startOK = [reader startReading];

    NSAssert( startOK && reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading, @"Ensure we've started reading." );

    NSAssert( _asset.providesPreciseDurationAndTiming, @"We expect the asset to provide accurate timing." );

    //
    // Start reading samples
    //

    CMSampleBufferRef sample = NULL;
    while(( sample = [output copyNextSampleBuffer] ))
    {
        CMTime presentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sample );
        if( data.length == 0 )
        {
            // First read - we should be at the expected presentation time requested.
            int32_t comparisonResult = CMTimeCompare( presentationTime, startTime );
            NSAssert( comparisonResult == 0, @"We expect sample accurate seeking" );
        }

        CMBlockBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer( sample );

        if( !buffer )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "avf : failed to obtain buffer" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        size_t lengthAtOffset = 0;
        size_t totalLength = 0;
        char *bufferData = NULL;

        if( CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer( buffer, 0, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, &bufferData ) != kCMBlockBufferNoErr )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "avf : failed to get sample\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( bufferData && lengthAtOffset )
        {
            [data appendBytes:bufferData length:lengthAtOffset];
        }

        CFRelease( sample );
    }

    NSAssert( reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted, @"Completed reading" );

    [output release];
    [reader release];

    return [NSData dataWithData:data];
}
```

## Notes

The presentation time that `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp` gives me seems to match what I sought after - but as it seems inaccurate, then I have no chance to correct and align the samples I retrieve.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Alternatively, is there a way to adapt `AVAssetTrack` to be used by `AVAudioFile` or `ExtAudioFile`?

Is it possible to access the audio track via `AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks`?

Is it possible to get at the audio stream from a video container in a different manner in macOS?

Comment: It should be noted that at times AVFoundation delivers fewer samples than are necessary to sufficiently satisfy the `durationTime` requirement. It isn't a problem to e.g. have a `durationTime` of `kCMTimePositiveInfinity` and simply read enough samples as required … it's the initial seek that is problematic.

Answer (score 4):

One procedure that works is to use AVAssetReader, to read your compressed AV file, in conjunction with AVAssetWriter, to write a new raw LPCM file of the audio samples.  Then one can quickly index through this new PCM file (or memory mapped array, if necessary) to extract exact sample-accurate ranges, without incurring VBR per-packet decoding size anomalies or depending on iOS CMTimeStamp algorithms outside one's control.

This may not be the most time or memory efficient procedure, but it works.

Comment: It would definitely work — however I would really like to avoid intermediate complete output of the entire source audio track to memory/disk. Using e.g. `AVAssetExportSession` and writing the audio track without re-encoding to disk (pass-through), and then reading that using audio-file only APIs works, but is a costly step.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another answer in which I incorrectly claimed 
 `AVAssetReader`/`AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` did not do sample accurate seeking, they do, but it looks broken when your audio track is embedded inside a movie file, so you've found a bug. Congratulations!

The audio track dumped with a pass through `AVAssetExportSession`, as mentioned in a comment on @hotpaw2's answer, works fine, even when you seek on non-packet boundaries (you happened to be seeking on packet boundaries, the linked file's has 1024 frames per packet - seeking off packet boundaries, your diffs are no longer zero, but they are very, very small/non audible) .

I didn't find a workaround, so reconsider dumping the compressed track. Is it that costly?  If you really don't want to do that, you can decode the raw packets yourself by passing `nil` `outputSettings:` to your `AVAssetReaderOutput` and running its output through an `AudioQueue` or (preferably?) an `AudioConverter` to get LPCM.

**NB** in this latter case, you *will* need to handle rounding up to packet boundaries when seeking.